# How to store output from a remote host in a variable bash script

Tags: bash

I need to get all the wars on a remote tomcat server printed via my bash script.
I am able to ssh on the remote server and execute the command to get wars with version :-

```
${SSH} ${DEST_USER}@${DESTHOST} "Command"
```

however if I am storing it in a variable I don't get any-thing:-

```
output=${SSH} ${DEST_USER}@${DESTHOST} "Command"
echo $output
```

Based on a bit research if I try it as

```
output=$(${SSH} ${DEST_USER}@${DESTHOST} "Command"
echo $output
```

I got my output stored (need to understand why?).

Secondly the output I got in a single line as:

```
abc_1.2.war ijk_2.2.war hij_3.2.war xyx_5.1.war
```

how can I format this output some thing like:

```
Name version
abc  1.2
ijk  2.2
hij  3.2
xyz  5.1
```

Answer (score 4):

Bash handles lines like this:

```
a=b c=d command
```

by temporarily setting environment variables "a" and "c" *only for the duration of the command*. They are not normal shell variables, and they won't exist after the command completes.

When you write

```
output=${SSH} ${DEST_USER}@${DESTHOST} "Command"
```

you are setting the "output" variable to the contents of "$SSH" for the duration of the "$DEST_USER@$DESTHOST" command (I'd expect you would receive a "command not found" error).

The way to capture the output of a command, as you have discovered, is with the `$()` syntax

```
output=$($SSH $DEST_USER@$DESTHOST "Command")
```

(Note you don't always have to put braces around your variable names, that's only strictly necessary when you need to separate the variable name from surrounding text)

---

For your text formatting question:

```
output="abc_1.2.war ijk_2.2.war hij_3.2.war xyx_5.1.war"
{
    echo Name version
    for word in $output; do                    # no quotes around $output here!
        IFS=_ read name version <<< "$word"
        echo "$name" "${version%.*}"
    done
} | column -t
```

```
Name  version
abc   1.2
ijk   2.2
hij   3.2
xyx   5.1
```

Here I use braces to group the header and the lines from the for-loop together to send them to column. I don't assume you know all the file extensions, but I do assume each file has an extension. The `"${version%.*}"` part removes the last dot and any following characters from the end of the value of the "version" variable.

Comment: Many thanks "Glenn" for the great response. (Apology though its written to avoid thanks but I can not find any other place to do that :-) )

Comment: I having a problem here :----  What I am trying to achieve here is to get name and version stored in variable name and version which are separated by a space (so using IFS as described below) 

IFS=' ' read name version <<< "$word" (word here is reading as abc 1.2)

however read only assigning values to name variable leaving version left out how to set it for space separation so 1.2 comes in version

Comment: If `word="abc 1.2"`, then you don't need to touch IFS: `read name version <<<"$word"` should work.

Comment: however if there is a need where I want to store value in two separate variable .i.e. name and version how can I achieve that in read function (.ie. name=abc and version=1.2) I was wondering if IFS on space sequance could be help-ful however its take values in name and version got no values on second iteration name got the version

Answer (score 0):

Try `echo "$output"` (i.e. quotes).

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with the 'why' right now. However you can produce the desired output from the variable(containing single line) as follows :

```
echo "Name   version"
echo $output | grep -Eo "[a-zA-Z]+_[0-9]+.[0-9]+"| tr '_' ' '
```